# Java audio Clip does not continue to loop after stopping on Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, audio, javasound

If I start playing a Clip with `loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY)` it works fine and loops indefinitely. 
However, if I 'pause' it with `stop` and then attempt to start looping again it only plays the remainder of the loop it was previously playing and doesn't continue looping.

This only happens on OS X as far as I know (it works fine in Windows).

Am I doing something wrong? From all the Clip documentation it didn't seem like it.

If I set the frame position back to 0 after stopping the clip will loop but that is not the desired effect (resuming from where it was).

SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class LoopSound {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //borrowed from http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info
        //the sound will not continue to loop on mac os x
        //it does continue looping correctly on ms windows
        URL url = new URL(
            "http://pscode.org/media/leftright.wav");
        final Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        // getAudioInputStream() also accepts a File or InputStream
        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.
            //getAudioInputStream( new File("filename") );
            getAudioInputStream( url );
        clip.open(ais);
        // loop continuously
        clip.loop(-1);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            boolean isPlaying = true;
            public void run() {

                JFrame window = new JFrame("test");
                window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                JToggleButton button = new JToggleButton("sound toggle");
                button.setSelected(true);
                button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                        if(isPlaying){
                            clip.stop();
                        }else{
                            clip.loop(-1);
                        }
                        isPlaying = !isPlaying;
                    }
                });

                window.add(button);
                window.pack();
                window.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: "*Relevant code:"* For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  You might base it on the **Playing a `Clip`** code in the [javasound info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info).  Use a `JToggleButton` rather than a mouse event to trigger/pause the looping.

Comment: 1) If you add @MyName to a comment I get notified of it!  I would not have known of the SSCCE if I had not seen the question come up in my 'daily summary' of javasound questions & got curious about it. 2) I am hoping another user (or 2) of OS X might pop by to provide a test.  I can merely reiterate your Windows result.  3) If we get those extra OS X/faulty test results, I am thinking it is time to look into raising a bug with the maker of that JRE.  They may not action it quickly, or at all, but if they don't get told about it, they surely won't fix it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thank you!
I tested this on Debian Linux with the OpenJDK and it seemed to work OK. 
To be honest I am finding Java to be surprisingly non-cross-platform (write once run anywhere), not only in Java Sound but also Swing and Swing events. 
Wondering if it's time for a re-write in C++ using QT or something...